# Reading a pdf file using bufferedreader and writing to a bytearrayoutputstream

Tags: java

How do I read a PDF file and write it in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

```
   /*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class NewClass2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File pdfFile = new File("C:\\Users\\311001\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication1\\src\\javaapplication1\\image\\test_01.pdf");
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(pdfFile);
            ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
            int l;
            while ((l = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, l);
            }
            input.close();
            byte[] pdfBytes = output.toByteArray();
            String pdfInString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes));
            JSONObject json1 = new JSONObject();
            json1.put("command", pdfInString);
            System.out.println(json1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream (pdfFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
byte [] buffer = new byte [65536];
int l;
while ((l = input.read (buffer)) > 0)
    output.write (buffer, 0, l);
input.close ();
byte [] pdfBytes = output.toByteArray ();
```

Comment: am not getting any output when i try to print by converting it like this String pdfInString = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(pdfBytes)); system.out.println(pdfinString);

Comment: @user1753035 In your code you just do not read anything, so the fact that nothing is printed is not surprising.

Comment: wat changes should i make ?